# Sealing a sprayer faucet leak?

Tags: leak, faucet, kitchen-sink

I've had a sprayer faucet in my kitchen sink since I bought the house over 8 years ago. Somewhat recently it sprung a little leak on the right side. Today I noticed that this leak has expanded from one little jet of water to three, so clearly it's getting worse. I'm not sure what the best method to deal with this is - will I need to just replace the whole sprayer? Or is there some sort of sealant or other substance I can patch on there? I have photos attached.

[image: leak 1]
[image: leak 2]

And here's [an animated version too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJktq.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It also looks like there is a small stream going down the spout towards the handle. My suspicion is that there is enough internal corrosion that you will likely, even if you seal all the current leaks, develop more in short order. If that was my home I would replace it. If cost of replacement is an issue, I would guess that some epoxy (J B Weld or similar) would be an ugly but functional temporary fix, until more corrosion eats through a different area.

Comment: It sounds like replacement is the way to go. In that case, having never replaced a faucet before, should I expect to be able to find the same model? Or will I likely be installing something totally new?

Comment: I am definitely not a plumber, but I have replaced my kitchen faucet before. It's not that hard, but don't expect to find the same model. The cutouts in the sink are usually a standard pattern, but you need to know the number of holes in the sink to find the right replacement. You can always use a faucet with a lesser number of holes required, but I would not purchase one that needs more holes than you have in the sink.